# android list view number of elements per page

Tags: listview

I have a listview where I have 50 elements being displayed. I have decided to paginate the view so on each part of the view there are 10 elements and then a next button is clicked to get to the next 10 elements. Is this good practice or are there better methods for pagination on mobile devices.

Comment: That kind of pagination sounds like an anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no pagination on mobile devices, not the way you use it. Your use is usually covered by vertical scrolling. If that's a problem because of performance or other reasons, you put your first batch of items on the screen and either a button or a gesture that says "Load more" and gets you to the second batch - but the layout is still vertical scrolling in a single list.

Pagination in the sense of moving horizontally between lists is used in two cases: you either move between large items, where the entire page is an item (e.g. a book or a contact card) or maybe a stack of two items, or you go through a number of *different* lists (e.g. in an email client one could be your inbox, another could be your sent items and another your contacts). But still each list here is vertical and you can scroll down it to reveal more items.

There's also paging through large grids, like the list of apps on your device, but that's not a list view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you lazy-load your pagination into one list.

Load up 10 initially and then when you are at the bottom of the list append a loader, fetch the next 10 items and replace the loader with the next pages results. Rinse, repeat.

I think it's also known as an infinite list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find pagination on Mobile Screens a good idea at all.
As others have suggested, have a lazy loading list which keeps loading the data until it runs out of it.

But please have a fast-scroll button available, unlike twitter's app, so that users can come back to the top whenever they want.

Moving page-by-page can be a very annoying experience. It's already quite annoying on many scenarios over the Web too.
I've noticed that information that needs to be read a little thoroughly than being skimmed through (like questions on StackOVerflow) can be presented with pagination, because then I'll take pain to read everything on a page and then move to another to read more. This bunching kind of make sense here.
But imagine a situation (like a real estate portal) where you are presented with thumbnails and short info about things/products and you just want to have a glance at them, then going through that whole info page-by-page is pretty annoying.

Without drifting the topic to the web, lets stick to the mobile experience, Pagination isn't quite preferred here, and I haven't seen many people doing it.